# fullPage.js, content div not properly placed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

You can see my problem and the code in the link below. I am trying to make the .bg div to completly cover the first section, but it ends up only covering 50%.

http://oskarvertetics.kaggteknik.se/portfolio/test2

I have tried playing around with different margins and paddings on different elements but can not get it to work in any way.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add top:0; in your .bg css

```
.bg {
 opacity: 0.5;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 5s;
 -moz-transition: opacity 5s;
 transition: opacity 5s;
 top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, uploaded the fix on the link above. And when we are on it, any idea how to make the text stay on top when you scroll up from the section below? Z-index doesn't seem to work for me...

Comment: your .introtext? If yeah, you can just put it outside the div#fullpage.

Comment: Yeah, but don't seem to work since it will have a fixed position on the viewport since it's outside the slides... :/